# CKEditor: Access insertHtml() method from external script

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am building a custom text editor using CKEditor and I want to write my own JavaScript functions to insert HTML into the CKEditor window.

CKEditor has a method called `editor.insertHtml()` that inserts HTML at the location of the cursor in the document. This method can be accessed from within a CKEditor plugin but I would prefer the freedom to write my own functions outside of CKEditor, then insert the resulting HTML into the editor.

So how do I access `editor.insertHtml()`? I have copied my code below. I tried using `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml()` but this doesn't work.

This question [CKEditor editor1.insertHtml() not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754831/ckeditor-editor1-inserthtml-not-working-for-me) suggests that I need to be listening for the `instanceReady` event, but I'm not sure how to do this so I would appreciate a more detailed explanation. Thank you!

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="editor1"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Replaces the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
    {
        height:"500", width:"1000"
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml('<h1>someText</h1>');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most likely you shouldn't use `insertHtml` in this case. I guess that you're trying to load data into editor, so either you should use `getData` or set that HTML as a textarea's value before loading editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [instanceReady](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceReady) event:

> Fired when a CKEDITOR instance is created, fully initialized and ready
>   for interaction.

You can use it as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    height: '500', 
    width: '1000',
    on: {
       instanceReady: function() {
           // this is current editor instance
           this.insertHtml( '<h1>someText</h1>' );
       }
    }
} );
```

To use the API of an instance, basically put your code in `instanceReady` callback. Otherwise, your code will be executed while the editor is not ready yet.